# Take different actions depending on value presence in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have table where I add changes in values of particular columns in other tables:

UpdatesLogTable:

| TableName | ColumnFilter | FilterName | FilterValue | Difference | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fruits | FruitName | Apple | 4 | 0 | 1/13/2021 |
| Fruits | FruitName | Pear | 5 | 0 | 1/13/2021 |

When I insert new records based on last update date of the tables I have issue determining the conditions for inserting.

For example, yesterday my inventory of `Apples` was equal to `4` and today it is `5`. So, in my UpdatesLog table I will insert `Fruits-FruitName-Apple-5`. In the column `Difference` I will calculate the difference between yesterday's and today's value which is `1`. This will be ok, since I already have Apple as value in FilterName column.

But if on my last update in `Fruits table` I add new `FruitName - Peach`, **how am I supposed to check that this value does not exist and add it with default `Difference value equal to 0`?**

Below is the last update on the 14-th of Jan:

| Fruits | FruitsInventory | LastUpdateDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 5 | 1/14/2021 |
| Pear | 9 | 1/14/2021 |
| Peach | 10 | 1/14/2021 |

And this is the result I am expecting:

| TableName | ColumnFilter | FilterName | FilterValue | Diff | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fruits | FruitName | Apple | 4 | 0 | 1/13/2021 |
| Fruits | FruitName | Pear | 5 | 0 | 1/13/2021 |
| Fruits | FruitName | **Apple** | **5** | **1** | **1/14/2021** |
| Fruits | FruitName | **Pear** | **9** | **4** | **1/14/2021** |
| Fruits | FruitName | **Peach** | **10** | **0** | **1/14/2021** |

This is my code in case I don't check if the fruit name exists:

```
INSERT INTO UpdatesLogTable(TableName, ColumnFilter, FilterName, FilterValue, [Difference], [Date])
SELECT [TableName]
    , [ColumnFilter]
    , [FilterName]
    , [FilterValue]
    , [Difference]
    , LUP as [Date]
FROM (
    SELECT tr.TableName
    , tr.ColumnFilter
    , tr.FilterName
    , tr.FilterValue
    , tr.[FilterValue] - ult.[FilterAbsValue] AS [Difference]
    , LUP
    FROM (SELECT
                'Fruits' as [TableName]
                , 'FruitName' as [ColumnFilter]
                ,  FruitName as [FilterName]
                , FruitsInventory AS [FilterValue]
                , MAX(LastUpdateDate as date) as LUP
            FROM Fruits  
            WHERE 1=1
            ) tr
    RIGHT JOIN UpdatesLogTable ult 
    ON tr.TableName = ult.TableName and tr.ColumnFilter = ult.ColumnFilter 
    WHERE hus.LastUpdateDate = (SELECT MAX(CAST(LastUpdateDate as date)) FROM UpdatesLogTable)
) a
```

I was thinking of LEFT or RIGHT join but this will work only if I know if the fruits variety is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Consider using triggers `ON INSERT` and `ON UPDATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question is rather confusing.  For instance:

- `#HistoryUpdatesSuccess` is not defined.
- You have a malformed aggregated subquery using `FRUITS`.
- The `JOIN` conditions are missing the filter value.

However, I think I understand what you want to do -- insert new rows with a `DIFF` column that incorporates the most recent data from the existing data.

This looks like a `LEFT JOIN` to the most recent record in the history table.  The rest is just `COALESCE()`.

```
INSERT INTO UpdatesLogTable(TableName, ColumnFilter, FilterName, FilterValue, [Difference], [Date])
    SELECT f.TableName, f.ColumnFilter, f.FilterName, f.FilterValue,
           COALESCE(f.FilterValue - ult.FilterValue, 0), 
           LUP as [Date]
    FROM FRUITS F LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT ult.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableName, ColumnFilter ORDER BY LastUpdateDate) as seqnum
          FROM UpdatesLogTable ult 
         ) ult
         ON tr.TableName = ult.TableName AND
            tr.ColumnFilter = ult.ColumnFilter AND
            tr.FilterName = ult.FilterName
            seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: But would this work if I have a new fruit. I think the left join will ignore it, since it has not existed before in the UpdatesLogTable. This is my main concern

Comment: @Yana . . . No, the `LEFT JOIN` does not ignore it.  That is why the query uses `LEFT JOIN` and not some other type of `JOIN`.

Comment: I fixed the #HistoryUpdatesSuccess :) It is the right name now.

Comment: Oh, I understand what happened here :) You left join the UpdatesLogTable to the Fruits table and this is why it will work. Thanks! I tried the opposite and this is why it did not work for me. Isn't ROW_NUMBER() ... PARTITION very slow if we have big tables?

Comment: @Yana . . . Everything is slow on large tables, so alternatives won't necessarily be much faster (actually a correlated subquery is often a bit faster but makes the query more complicated particularly for an outer join).